# Sublime3 automatically exit when enter the word "link" in a HTML file

Tags: sublimetext3

When I enter the word "link" in a *.html within sublime3 ,the sublime automatically exits.

Comment: Your question isn't a question, but I would suggest you check the packages that you have installed to see if one of them might have some sort of special functionality that's causing the crash here to happen.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I have re-installed then everything works again.